# Cakephp How do i search for a specific value in data requested from a form

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a form where students enter their subjects results.Now if on the subjects list,English was failed i.e(D,E),or has not been entered they must not be directed to the next page.

My controller receives the data as following before saving

```
for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($this->data['ApplicantOlevelQualification']['olevel_subject_code']); $i++) {

                if ($this->data['ApplicantOlevelQualification']['olevel_subject_code'][$i] != "") {
                    $this->ApplicantOlevelQualification->create();
                    $this->ApplicantOlevelQualification->id = null;
                    $this->ApplicantOlevelQualification->set(array(
                            'applicants_detail_id' => $app_id,
                            'olevel_subject_code' => $this->data['ApplicantOlevelQualification']['olevel_subject_code'][$i],
                            'grade' => $this->data['ApplicantOlevelQualification']['grade'][$i],
                            'centre_number'=> $centre_number, 
                            'candidate_number'=> $candidate_number, 
                            'exam_body_code'=> $exam_body_code,
                            'year_written'=> $year_written,

                        )
                    );
```

My save after this is

```
if ($this->ApplicantOlevelQualification->save()) {      
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your O\'level Qualifications have been saved'));
                    }   else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your O\'level Qualifications failed to save.'));
                    }
                }
```

So guys my English has

```
 'olevel_subject_code' = 8900,
```

and i want only students with grades A,B,C in English

```
   'grade'=A,B or C
```

to save and procceed,the rest  must remain on that view.My model name is ApplicantOlevelQualification,i don't know where exactly and how i can do my validation.Thank you in advance for helping

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but sounds like a condensed version of your question could be something like this?  "I want to validate a specific field to check if it's the string 'A', 'B', or 'C'.  Anything else should fail validation."

Comment: yes hey,thats what i really want

Answer (score 0):

As far as I tried to understand your problem, you can impose an if condition just after the loop starting. You can check whether grade exists between some specific values or not.
Please elaborate more, if it does not work for you.

Comment: Thanx for responding,but hey how do i find the grade for English only,thats where i'm facing a bigger challenge.I have got the subject_code for English 8900.So how can i search for specific values, eg grade with conditions before saving my data.